# number of valuation ring of $\Bbb Q_p((T))$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, p-adic-number-theory, valuation-theory

I would like to know the number of valuation rings of  $\Bbb Q_p((T))$.
I know $\Bbb Q_p$ has $2$ valuation rings, that is,$\Bbb Q_p$ and $\Bbb Z_p$.
Every algebraic extension of $\Bbb Q_p$ has more than $2$ valuation rings because of extension theorem on valuation.But $\Bbb Q_p((T))$ is not algebraic over $\Bbb Q_p$,I am at a loss.

How many valuation rings of  $\Bbb Q_p((T))$ are there?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What definition of "valuation ring" are you working with here? I would have expected something like $\mathbb Q_p[[T]]$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4000836/96384

Comment: Let K be a given field, then valuation ring R of K is a ring R which satisfies FracR＝K,and  K＝R∪R^-1.

Comment: Well then $\mathbb Z_p$ and $\mathbb Q_p$ are not valuation rings of the field $K=\mathbb Q_p((T))$. But there is one in my first comment, and one in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3959796/96384.

Comment: Ofcourse I know that. Zp and Qp are example of valuation ring of Qp, as I wrote.

Comment: I'm looking for a simple example of field which has 3 valuation ring, that is my purpose.Does the field of this title have just 2 valuation rings? You seem just say there are 'more than' two valuation rings.

Comment: Ah sorry, I misread your example there.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg It seems the OP doesn't care of answers to his previous questions https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4074221/number-of-valuation-ring-of-a-given-field He meant **discrete** valuation rings with fraction field $\Bbb{Q}_p((T))$ (there are many more non-discrete ones)

Comment: Every algebraic extension of $\Bbb{Q}_p$ has only one discrete valuation.

Comment: If we work with the definition OP gives in his first comment, then, as said in my linked post, $R:= \{\sum_{i \ge 0} a_i T^i \in \mathbb Q_p[[T]]: a_0 \in \mathbb Z_p\}$ is a valuation ring of $\mathbb Q_p((T))$. Surely it is not a **D**VR. @bellow, please confirm whether this ring matches your criterion, or else adjust your criterion. (And if reuns is right that you're only after DVR's, his answer seems right.)

Comment: I of course don't assume DVR.Your ring R matches my criterion. I really don't see why teacher reuns assume valuation ring to be DVR, that's not what I meant. To say the truth, I couldn't understand his answer to my previous post. I proposed the question that ' Can we find a field which has just n valuation ring?$. And I don't know teacher reuns answers this question. For example, what is an example of a field which has just 3 valuation ring ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [valuation ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valuation_ring) as you define it in a comment can also be described via a valuation, i.e. a surjective homomorphism $v: K^\times \twoheadrightarrow \Gamma$ onto a totally ordered abelian group $\Gamma$.

You should first of all note (also w.r.t. [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4074221/96384)) that if we stay in this generality, almost all fields you can reasonably think of have infinitely many valuation rings, although you might not be able to see them:

Namely, let $K$ be **any (!)** field that embeds into $\mathbb C$ (and unless you have a good point against the axiom of choice, this includes all $\mathbb Q_p$ and also the example $\mathbb Q_p((T))$ in this question). Now there are isomorphisms (unless you have a good point against the axiom of choice) $\mathbb C \simeq \mathbb C_\ell$ where $\mathbb C_\ell$ is the completion of the algebraic closure of the $\ell$-adic numbers $\mathbb Q_\ell$ for your second favourite prime $\ell$. Said field $\mathbb C_\ell$ comes naturally equipped with its $\ell$-adic valuation $v_\ell$ with value group (written multiplicatively) $\Gamma = \ell^\mathbb Q$. The restriction of this valuation along the isomorphisms and to the field $K$ is a valuation on $K$, which when restricted to $\mathbb Q$ gives the $\ell$-adic valuation. In particular, all these valuations are distinct and thus we have (modulo choice) infinitely many distinct valuation rings in $K$.

So that kind of dooms your hope to find a field with three (or any finite number of) valuation rings, at least in characteristic $0$. (Update: As reuns comments and I spelled out in an answer to your previous question, actually every field that is not algebraic over some $\mathbb F_p$ has infinitely many valuation rings -- and those that are algebraic over some $\mathbb F_p$ of course have only one, namely themselves.)

---

Good news is, if you restrict your search to valuation rings whose value group $\Gamma$ (from now on written additively) is discrete in the sense that it has a smallest element $>0_\Gamma$ (which unfortunately is not the same as what we call a DVR; the difference is that here I allow "discrete" value groups of higher rank, i.e. basically $\mathbb Z^n$), then I think you've found a match here.

To see that, adapt reuns' beautiful answer: The $n$-divisibility of that big subgroup $(1+p\Bbb{Z}_p+T \Bbb{Q}_p[[T]], \cdot) \subset K^\times$ still shows (because of our "dsicreteness" assumption) that all its elements must have value $0$, and of course so do all roots of unity; if $v(p)=0$ continue as in his proof and either get the trivial valuation $w_0(K^\times)=0$ i.e.

$$R_0=K$$

or the discrete (rank 1) valuation $w_1(\sum a_i T^i)=\min(i: a_i \neq 0)$ i.e.

$$R_1= \mathbb Q_p[[T]].$$

But now we could also have the option that $v(p) > 0$ as long as we make sure (cf. reuns' first bullet) that $v(p^{-r}T)$ is always $\ge 0$, meaning that the value of $T$ has to be "infinitely bigger" than that of $p$. That forces us basically to have $\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z$ as value group, with the generator $v(T) := (1,0)$ "infinitely bigger" than the other generator $v(p)=(0,1)$, i.e. the lexicographic order. Call this rank 2 valuation $w_2 : K^\times \rightarrow \mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z $, it is explicitly given on $x= \sum a_i T^i$ as

$$w_2(x) := \left(w_1(x), v_p(a_{w_1(x)})\right).$$

Its valuation ring is

$$R_2 = \{x \in K: w_2(x) \ge (0,0)\} = \{\sum_{i \ge 0} a_i X^i \in \mathbb Q_p[[X]]: a_0 \in \mathbb Z_p\}$$

and there you got your three possible valuation rings with "discrete" value groups (of ranks $0,1,2$) $R_0, R_1, R_2$.

Compare the other answers to [Concrete examples of valuation rings of rank two.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1307/96384) for another example.

Comment: Sorry, but why you restrict value group to discrete ones? As you say, I agree that almost all fields has infinitely many values except finite field（with 1 valuation ring）, local fields（with 2 valuation ring）. So I'm searching for a field with finite valuation（with more than ３ valuation ring）.

Comment: Have you read the third paragraph? If we don't make that restriction, e.g. all algebraic extensions of $\mathbb Q_p$ do *not* (as you claim) have 2, but infinitely many valuation rings (and even of rank 1: but with *dense* value group), and the same is true for the field in this question. I understand user reuns has told you the same thing before.

Comment: I understand your claim but my problem awareness is to find a field which has 'finitely' many more than 3 valuation ring（not restricted to discrete valuation）,as  I said again and again.  So, the titled field of this question and algebraic extension of Qp is out of the field I'm looking for. This is a fruit you and reuns gave me, thank you so much.But, although I'm asking for a field which has 'finitely' many（more than 3）valuation ring field, you and reuns always shows me an example of a field which has infinitely many valuation ring.

Comment: @bellow $K$ has finitely many valuations (discrete and non-discrete, any kind of value group) iff it is contained in $\overline{\Bbb{F}}_p$ for some $p$ (having only the trivial valuation). Otherwise it contains $\Bbb{F}_p(x)$ or $\Bbb{Q}$ whose infinitely many valuations extend to $K$.

Comment: Thank you, but the field K contained in a algebraic closure of Fp only has '1' valuation ring. As I said again and again,I' m looking for a field with 'finitely more than 3' valuation ring.

Comment: @bellow, as reuns has told you again and again, **there is no field which has finitely more than 3 valuation rings**. He literally just gave the shortest argument that every field has either one, or infinitely many valuation rings. If you want I can spell that out as an answer to your previous question.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you... Now, I am very thankful to you and reuns. If you are ok, please spell out an answer to my previous question.

Answer (score 2):

There is only one (non-trivial) **discrete** valuation on $\Bbb{Q}_p((T))$.

For all $f\in 1+p\Bbb{Z}_p+T \Bbb{Q}_p[[T]]$ the binomial series gives that $f^{1/n}\in \Bbb{Q}_p((T))$ whenever $p\nmid n$. Therefore, that $v$ is discrete implies $v(f)=0$.

Decompose
$$\Bbb{Q}_p((T))^\times = T^\Bbb{Z} p^\Bbb{Z} \langle \zeta_{p-1}\rangle \ (1+p\Bbb{Z}_p+T \Bbb{Q}_p[[T]])$$
Thus, it remains to find $v(\zeta_{p-1}),v(p)$ and $v(T)$.

Since  $(\zeta_{p-1})^{p-1}=1$ we must have $v(\zeta_{p-1})=0$.

- If $v(p)\ne 0$, then $p$ is a multiple of $1$ so we must have $v(p)>0$. For $r$ large enough we have $v(p^{-r} T)<0$ so that $v(1+p^{-r} T)<0$, a contradiction.
- Whence $v(p)=0$. We must have $v(T)\ne 0$ for $v$ being non-trivial.

  $v(T)<0$ would contradict $v(1+T)=0$ so we must have $v(T)>0$ and hence ​$$\{ x\in \Bbb{Q}_p((T))^\times,v(x)\ge 0\} = \Bbb{Q}_p[[T]]-0$$

Comment: Would not the following hold for $F$ *any* field of characteristic $0$: $F((T))^\times \simeq T^{\mathbb Z} \times F^\times \times (1+TF[[T]])$, the last factor is $n$-divisible for infinitely many $n$ so has valuation $0$. Then for any $a \in F^\times$ if $v(a) \neq 0$ analogous to your argument one would get $v(1+a^rT)  < 0$ for $r$ big or small enough, contradiction, so $v(F^\times)=0$. Then for $v$ to be non-trivial $v(T) > 0$ and proceeding as you do. Or where's my mistake?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Seems right. As a sanity check $k[[x]][[y]]=k[[y]][[x]]$ but $k((x))((y))\ne k((y))((x))$ and $\inf v(a_n)$ isn't a valuation on $\Bbb{Q}_p((T))$